# Why Not Garbage Values

Tags: c, algorithm

Guys this is a program which i ran on my compiler and i am getting **30 0 0 0** as the output.Can one explain me why the values are 0 .Because in 2'nd loop tmp would point to something outside the array so wouldn't it be a garbage value. Why Garbage values are not getting printed instead 0's are coming in the output.

```
void main()
{
  int array[4]={10,20,30,40};
  int *tmp=array;
  for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    tmp+=sizeof(int);
    printf("%d",*tmp);
  }
  getch();
}
```

Comment: It's a garbage value. There's nothing that says it can't be zero.

Comment: Your code won't even compile. Return type of `main()` should be `int`, getch() is non standard./

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav - "Nonstandard code" doesn't mean "Non-compiling code." It _shouldn't_ compile, but it probably will on many compilers (with the settings turned down).

Comment: some compilers are more forgiving than others

Comment: Guys When i am saying i have run this program then instead of arguing over whether this program would run or not you must answer my query.

Comment: Disregard my (deleted) duplicate comment, I assumed he was actually printing uninitialized values without reading.

Comment: @yogi15490 - You've got several good answers. I don't want to add to the noise since they're right, but we can still help you do better in other areas in the future (like that `void main()` I mentioned :P).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the sizeof(int) is 2 bytes that is why it prints 30  (initially the pointer is pointing to memory location having value 10 and then it points to 30, it prints this value subsequently).

Next again the pointer moves ahead by 2 places so it skips 40 and moves out of bounds.
0 as has been stated earlier is a random garbage value though it looks as if the values are proper.Try executing the code again after declaring some more variables along with the array and observe the output.

Answer (score 5):

You do not add `sizeof(int)` to an `int` pointer to get to the next array element; you add 1. Adding `sizeof(int)` will advance by `sizeof(int)` *elements* (probably 4 elements), putting you past the end of the array. This is your problem.

**Edit:** OK apparently the program was part of an interview question meant to illustrate undefined behavior, and the correct answer to the interview question is that once undefined behavior has been invoked, anything could happen.

Comment: This is exactly what OP is trying to do. I just don't understand why OP choosed `sizeof(int)` to represent `4`.

Comment: @ruslik - With the OP's results it looks like `sizeof(int)` is 2 for him.

Comment: @ruslik: Because `sizeof(int)` isn't always a representation of `4`?

Comment: Guys this question had been asked in adobe interview I haven't done the coding of this program.

Comment: Then this is yet another stupid "Why doesn't undefined behavior do what I expect it to?" question....

Comment: Guys this question had been asked in adobe interview I haven't done the coding of this program.You have not interpreted my question correctly.This program has been deliberately asked by an interviewer and what my question is why the output comprise of 0's not garbage values

Comment: @yogi15490: and the answer is that, once you've invoked UB, **all** bets are off. 0 is just as much garbage as 1328723 but there's no reason it couldn't print 1.5 or "goodbye world" or do anything else. There is not even a guarantee that *earlier* output in the program is correct if the program *ever* invokes UB.

Answer (score 3):

0 can be a garbage value too. it depends on what is in the memory due to compiler switches etc.

try compiling your code in release mode and your probably will get other funny numbers

Comment: A lot of systems will zero a memory page before allocating it to a program.  This is to prevent salvaging date from reused memory pages.  This is standard security.